# Why Docker cant launch container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose file with one image (httpd) and one volume that look into ./ folder (It contains only one `index.html` static file). When I start my computer I launch this image with

```
docker-compose up
```

And it works, I see message

```
Starting mysiteloc_app_1        ... done
```

And can access it via localhost.

But when I wait several hours (seriously, I do nothing, for experiment I just wait 3 hours without touching keyboard or mouse) and try to use

```
docker-compose up
```

I get message

```
mysiteloc_redis_1 is up-to-date
```

But if I restart docker daemon all works nice. What the problem? Docker reference say that if i get `up-to date` message I changed volume or docker-compose.yml and need to rebuild, but firstly I dont changed anything, secondly why after reboot it works without rebuild?

P.S: When I write this message I realised that use `httpd:latest` image. Problem may be related with minor httpd updates? But then why I dont need rebuild after restarting daemon?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Also, is your title correct? It doesn't make alot of sense.

Comment: My problem is that without daemon restart docker cant launch container.

Title is really incorrect,I corrected it

Comment: Could you provide the docker-compose.yml And the corresponding dockerfiles?

Answer (score 1):

After getting your site up with `docker-compose up` there is No practical reason for running `docker-compose up` again without making any changes, because the container is running.

So docker deamon informs you there is nothing New to do.

Comment: But I get this error even after `docker-compose stop` or `docker-compose down` command

Comment: Did you check if all containers are stopped successfuly?

Comment: Yes,`docker ps` say that  they are stopped